# Ошибка метода Битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

```
use Bitrix\Main\Loader; 
use Bitrix\Main\SiteTable; 
use Bitrix\Main\Config\Option; 
use Bitrix\Currency\CurrencyTable; 

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/modules/main/include/prolog_admin_before.php'); 
require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/bitrix/modules/catalog/prolog.php'); 
Loader::includeModule('catalog'); 
$var = CCatalogDocs::add( 
"DOC_TYPE" => "A", 
"SITE_ID" => "s1", 
"DATE_DOCUMENT" => "11.07.2016 17:16:55", 
"CREATED_BY" => "1", 
"MODIFIED_BY" => "1", 
"COMMENTARY" => "", 
"CONTRACTOR_ID" => "1", 
"CURRENCY" => "EUR", 
"TOTAL" => "22" 
); 
echo $var;?>
```

`CCatalogDocs::add` использую данный метод битрикс. В документации ничего про него нет. Подключения моделей все нормально, при выполнении метода валится сайт и не показывает никаких ошибок.

Comment: В логах какая-то информация есть? Без сообщения об ошибке будет трудно помочь.

Comment: Никакой ошибки не выводится совершенно. Какая та фигня.

Comment: включен ли у Вас режим отладки? если да, то он настроен на вывод на экран или в лог? что в момент обращения к странице пишется в access лог? что в error лог? здесь не клуб анонимных телепатов, читайте рубрику [как задавать вопросы](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/asking) прежде чем задать вопрос

Comment: Посмотрите, что вы передаёте в качестве параметра. Нужно передавать массив.